# Output argument not assigned during call

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to create a recursive paint/fill algorithm that fills anything connected with a given pixel (using 8 neighbors) in a binary image with the same value. I'm passing in the image (img), the pixel coordinates (x,y), the value to be filled in (index), a cell(25,1) list to be filled with the points colored, and the number of points colored (pt). My code as below works for a given connected region until the deepest recursion returns at which point it gives the error

```
Output argument "pt" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "paintfill".
```

When I say it works I mean that each point is added to points correctly and the pixel in img is updated to be index.

```
function [ img, points, pt] = paintfill( img, x, y, index, points, pt)

sz = size(img);
if y <= sz(1) && x <= sz(2) %Valid pixel
    if img(y,x) == 255 %Unprocessed foreground pixel
        img(y,x) = index;
        points{pt,1} = [y,x];
        pt = pt+1;
        % 8 Neighbor
        [img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x+1, y+1, index, points, pt);
        [img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x+1, y, index, points, pt);
        [img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x+1, y-1, index, points, pt);
        [img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x, y+1, index, points, pt);
        [img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x, y-1, index, points, pt);
        [img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x-1, y+1, index, points, pt);
        [img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x-1, y, index, points, pt);
        [img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x-1, y-1, points, pt);
    end
end
end
```

Where I'm lost is that pt is passed in as an input so how could it not be assigned?

Comment: sure that's the actual error? The algorithm should fail when either `x` or `y` reach `0`, as that is not a valid index and `if img(y,x) == 255` will throw an error.

Comment: zeeMonkeez is correct.  You need to make sure the image coordinates don't go below 1 (`x = 1` or `y = 1`).

Comment: That is another error in the code though the one I asked about is also occurring , but thanks for pointing that out (can't believe I missed it). I've been "lucky" in that the image I've been testing on has 0 along the top and left boundaries but obviously that won't always be the case. Still, the original question stands.

Comment: Could it be that in your last line you forgot the `index` argument? I.e. it is `[img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x-1, y-1, points, pt);` but should be `[img, points, pt] = paintfill(img, x-1, y-1, index, points, pt);`?

Comment: Mind you, unless you adjust the recursion limit, this algorithm will not be able to process images larger than 500px.